# calculate center point of multiple latlang in android google map?

Tags: android

I'm looking for a solution that calculates the center between several latitude-longitude coordinates (for example, to simply center a map to the center of a google-maps polygon).I m storing latlang coordinates into arraylist.

Comment: do you want to center map so maximum possible markers are visible to user on map?

Answer (score 8):

Use the [`LatLngBounds.Builder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds.Builder.html).

Once you create an instance keep adding `LatLng`s to it. Finally `build()` it and call `getCenter()` on the resulting `LatLngBounds` object.

You can only add positions to the builder, it cannot subtract.

Comment: Such a simple solution! :)

Answer (score 2):

this one worked for me

```
   LatLng getCenterPointInPolygon(Polygon polygon) {
    LatLngBounds.Builder latLngBounds = LatLngBounds.builder();
    for (LatLng latLng : polygon.getPoints()) {
        latLngBounds.include(latLng);
    }
    return latLngBounds.build().getCenter();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic 3D Calculus. Build a function that receives a point and outputs the sum of the distances to each position on the map. Then, use calculus to find the point where the function reaches its minimum. That is the center.